Vue + Vite не применяются изменения в css файлах
Vue 3 + Vite не отслеживает изменения в css файлах, соответственно хот релоад не срабатывает, подключенных к компоненту через <style src="./style.css" /> приходится каждый раз перезапускать dev сервер. При этом если подключить стили через import внутри script - всё ок. Подскажите, почему так и куда копать?

Правильно импортировать внутри style или script блока

Если требуется подключить стиль по всему проекту, то в main.js добавляешь импорт:
import '@/assets/style.css';   

Если добавляешь в конкретный компонент, то импортируешь в блок style:
@import '@/assets/variables.css';

